# How do I suppress the "Save a local copy" prompt in clear case?

Tags: clearcase, checkin

## Background

In clearcase, whenever you [uncheckout](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_uncheckout.htm), or [check in](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkin.htm) files, you get a prompt that says:

```
Save private copy of <file> ? [yes]
```

For each individual file.

### Problem

I am trying to check in hundreds of files at once with a script and I know I don't want to save a private copy of any of them.  How do I suppress this prompt so I don't have to manually enter `n` or `no` for each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, you can `cleartool checkout -rm` or `cleartool checkout -keep` in order to not save, or save a copy of the file.

By using those options, you will get a non-interactive command and won't have to enter y/n for each file.